# Allowing an estimator to say "I don't know"

Tags: regression, supervised-learning

I have a standard supervised regression problem, except that the estimator is not strictly required to produce a prediction in every case: the machine is allowed to say "I don't know" in *x* percent of cases.

We want an estimator that will learn to minimize loss across the predictions that are given. So, it will learn to give the "I don't know" response in cases where the prediction error is expected to be highest.

Are there any algorithms that do this? I've thought about using a model that provides some estimate of the variance in it's own predictions (Gaussian process regression, for example. Or even training a second model to predict variance in the main estimator's predictions) and setting an "I don't know" threshold on that variance. Are there better approaches I'm overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use a probabilistic model and use the fitted probability of class membership (or whatever your outcome is) to make this decision?

Comment: Good point @psboonstra, I just realized I didn't specify this was a regression problem. Edited the description.
Still you're point is well taken; are there good probabilistic regression approaches you think would work for this?

Comment: I might not be understanding the question, but it seems like you could just use logistic regression (assuming your outcome is binary) to get at what you're trying to do. "I don't know" is a subjective and contextual definition, but, as an example, you could just fit a logistic regression and then declare that any fitted probability between 0.1 and 0.9 means 'I don't know'.

Comment: Thanks @psboonstra. Again, it's a regression problem as opposed to classification. So the outcome is not binary - it's a continuous variable.

Comment: But the decision to say "I don't know" is implicitly binary - you either say "I don't know" or "I know", and if you say "I know", you also provide the numeric prediction.

Comment: True @jbowman. I guess the real question here is, what principled method should the machine use to decide when to say "I don't know"? I mentioned in the question the idea of having a second model that estimates the error in the primary model's predictions. Is that what you're thinking?

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach would be to avoid fiddling with the model fitting but rather report the standard error of each observation's prediction, e.g. $\mathrm{sd}(x\hat\beta)$, if you're using a linear predictor, or the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) and make an ad-hoc determination about how large these values need to be to warrant saying 'I don't know'.

A more complicated approach would be to put a spike-slab-type prior on your error distribution, where the error from each observation is assumed to latently come from this distribution. The spike component corresponds to the observations that you would be confident about, and the slab component corresponds to the observations that you say 'I don't know'. Each observations gets a posterior probability of slab-iness, and you make your determination based upon that.

Comment: note: your spike shouldn't be a point-mass but rather a typical error distribution, and your slab should be something that is similar but with much heavier tails